# Angularjs and bootstrap library files not found (404) http-serve

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, node-modules

I am creating a small app to learn angularjs and installed it and other dependencies using npm. To serve the application I installed http-server package via npm locally. My app directory structure looks like so

restaurant > app, node_modules, package.json

The app folder looks like

app > index.html, app.js

Inside my index.html i tried referencing angular.min.js and bootstrap css files from node_modules like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../app.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js>"></script>
```

Inside of app.js I have declared an angularjs module so i can print an interpolation result from my index.html file.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "restaurant",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An AngularJS app for Restaurants",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 4000 ./app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

When i run npm start and go to localhost:4000/index.html it says

```
GET http://localhost:4000/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
index.html:4

GET http://localhost:4000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at app.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.js:1
index.html:6 GET

http://localhost:4000/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js%3E net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

My question is do I have to write some command inside my package to copy angularjs and other library files inside some other folder in my app directory?

If not why is localhost:4000/index.html not able to find these files?

TIA for any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the web server to serve everything under the directory `app`. So, on the web server, the **root** in the `app`directory. So the only two files that can ber served are `/index.html` (which the server finds in its root directory: `app`), and `/app.js` (which it also finds in its root directory `app`).

The root, by definition, is the root. There is nothing above the root, otherwise it wouldn't be the root. So asking for `../anything`when you're already at the root makes no sense.

Side note: AngularJS is basically an officially abandoned framework. It's still being maintained (security bug fixes only, see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status)) for a few months, and then it's finished. Why are you learning an abandoned framework?

Comment: I thought the same as well and didn't know how I could reference library files in my index.html

I got over the problem by installing cpx to copy library files (I am sure there are other ways unknown to me) in a directory inside app/ using the postinstall command in my package.json 

To answer your side note I already know angularjs as that's the framework we currently use at work but I thought of brushing up on my skills to answer any questions that may come up during future interviews.

What I don't know much about is how npm and node modules and the newer javascript ecosystem works.